# Best Js framework can be used with sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I new in **Sharepoint**, i wanna create forms, session, CRUD operations, send messages via Skype API.

i am confused which JS framework i have to use with Sharepoint in client-side and why?

Angular JS, View JS, Knockout JS, React JS.. Or other JS framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using right now React Js with SharePoint for more than 2 years. I didn't find any issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is agnostic to these frameworks. Means, it does not use any of the listed frameworks. Also it does not require you to use any of those frameworks. So you can choose whatever you know better. Or you can go without any framework at all.